# A problem on probability theory and geometry

Tags: geometry, probability-theory

I am stuck on the following problem: given a circle of radius $R$ I put randomly $N$ points inside the circle. What is the probability to have the distances of every point from the other greather than a defined quantity $d_{min}$? I can suppose to have a pencil falling $N$ times from the ceiling of the room where is the circle on a table and assuming the pencil is forced to fall on it, this pencil will mark randomly $N$ points. Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming a uniform distribution of points over the interior of the circle? I guess so. Simulations should be easy, but an exact formula sounds tricky. Interesting.

Comment: @MvG: for the sake of simplicity, we can assume the distribution is uniform.

Comment: Uniform according to what metric?

Comment: @MarkPing: uniform in the sense that every point inside the circunference has the same probability to be marked from the pencil.

Comment: There are infinitely many points of zero area, so there are many different distributions which have the same (i.e. zero) probability for any specific point. A typical requirement would be probabilities proportional to area: the bigger an area you select, the bigger the chances of a pencil mark within that area. Half the circle area would get half the hits, no matter the shape used to denote that half area.